# Converting float vector to 16-bit int without saturating

Tags: c++, c, performance, sse

I want to convert a floating point value to a 16-bit unsigned integer without saturating (wraparound/overflow instead).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void satur_wrap()
{
    const float bigVal = 99000.f;
    const __m128 bigValVec = _mm_set1_ps(bigVal);

    const __m64 outVec64 =_mm_cvtps_pi16(bigValVec);

#if 0
    const __m128i outVec = _mm_movpi64_epi64(outVec64);
#else

    #if 1
        const __m128i outVec  = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_cvttps_epi32(bigValVec), _mm_cvttps_epi32(bigValVec));
    #else
        const __m128i outVec  = _mm_cvttps_epi32(bigValVec);
    #endif

#endif

    uint16_t *outVals = NULL;
    posix_memalign((void **) &outVals, sizeof(__m128i), sizeof(__m128i));

    _mm_store_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i *>(outVals), outVec);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(outVec) / sizeof(*outVals); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "outVals[" << i << "]: " << outVals[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl
        << "\tbigVal: " << bigVal << std::endl
        << "\t(unsigned short) bigVal: " << ((unsigned short) bigVal)  << std::endl
        << "\t((unsigned short)((int) bigVal)): " << ((unsigned short)((int) bigVal)) << std::endl
        << std::endl;
}
```

Sample execution:

```
$ ./row
outVals[0]: 32767
outVals[1]: 32767
outVals[2]: 32767
outVals[3]: 32767
outVals[4]: 32767
outVals[5]: 32767
outVals[6]: 32767
outVals[7]: 32767

        bigVal: 99000
        (unsigned short) bigVal: 65535
        ((unsigned short)((int) bigVal)): 33464
```

The `((unsigned short)((int) bigVal))` expression works as desired (but it's probably UB, right?).  But I can't find something quite similar with SSE.  I must be missing something, but I couldn't find a primitive to convert four 32-bit `float`s to four 32-bit `int`s.

---

EDIT: Oops, I figured it would be "normal" for 32-bit integer -> 16-bit unsigned integer conversion to use wraparound.  But I've since learned that `_mm_packs_epi32` uses signed-saturate (and there doesn't appear to be a `_mm_packus_epi32`).  Is there a way to set the mode, or another primitive besides `_mm_packus_epi32`?

Comment: By the way you `_mm_store_si128` is probably not gonna work, since `outVals` is probably not 16-byte aligned. Either use `_mm_storeu_si128` for unalgined load or care for proper alignment of `outVals`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot the posix_memalign in my example.

Comment: See: `CVTTPS2DQ` aka `_mm_cvttps_epi32`

Comment: Hey @PaulR, that looks like it'll work perfectly!  Make it an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: @Brian: no problem - comment now converted to an answer.

Comment: Oops.  Question rephrased with more detail.  I thought it'd be a short putt to go from 32-bit signed integer-vector to 16-bit unsigned integer vector.

Comment: @Brian: see my updated answer below for a complete working implementation as per your latest requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm answering only part of the question concerning 32-bit integer -> 16-bit unsigned integer conversion.

Since you need a wraparound, just take the low-order word of each double-word containing 32-bit integer. These 16-bit integers are interleaved with 16-bit pieces of unused data, so it may be convenient to pack them into a contiguous array. The easiest way to do this is using `_mm_shuffle_epi8` intrinsic (SSSE3).

If you want your program to be more portable and require only SSE2 instruction set, you can pack the values with `_mm_packs_epi32`, but disable its saturating behavior with following trick:

```
x = _mm_slli_epi32(x, 16);
y = _mm_slli_epi32(y, 16);

x = _mm_srai_epi32(x, 16);
y = _mm_srai_epi32(y, 16);

x = _mm_packs_epi32(x, y);
```

This trick works because it performs sign extension of 16-bit values, which makes signed saturation a no-op.

The same trick works with `_mm_packus_epi32`:

```
x = _mm_and_si128(x, _mm_set1_epi32(65535));
y = _mm_and_si128(y, _mm_set1_epi32(65535));
x = _mm_packus_epi32(x, y);
```

This trick works because it performs zero extension of 16-bit values, which makes unsigned saturation a no-op. It is easier to perform zero extension, but you need SSE4.1 instruction set to make `_mm_packus_epi32` available.

It is possible to pack 8 16-bit integers using a single instruction: `_mm_perm_epi8`. But this requires pretty rare XOP instruction set.

---

And here are several words about saturated conversion.

In fact `_mm_packus_epi32` intrinsic is available if you change `#include <xmmintrin.h>` to `#include <smmintrin.h>` or `#include <x86intrin.h>`. You need both your CPU and compiler to support SSE4.1 extensions.

If you have no SSE4.1-compatible CPU or compiler or want your program to be more portable, substitute `_mm_packus_epi32` intrinsic with code like this:

```
__m128i m1 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(x, _mm_set1_epi32(0));
__m128i m2 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(x, _mm_set1_epi32(65535));
x = _mm_and_si128(x, m1);
x = _mm_or_si128(x, m2);
```

Comment: But I don't want to saturate.  I want overflow/wraparound as in the `((unsigned short)((int) bigVal))` expression.  Your example will saturate, right?

Comment: I was probably unclear in asking for `_mm_packus_epi32`, it's unrelated or at least not the main problem.  Didn't know about `<smmintrin.h>`, though.  +1.

Comment: If you need wraparound, just take the low-order word of each doubleword containing 32-bit integer. You could use `_mm_shuffle_epi8` intrinsic (SSSE3) to prepare a contiguous array of these 16-bit integers. But there is nothing to convert in this case.

Comment: Ok, wow, looks worthwhile.  This will require some more RTFMing and experimentation, will get back to you.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're probably looking for the `CVTTPS2DQ` instruction, the intrinsic for which is `_mm_cvttps_epi32`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8c5hx3b(v=vs.71).aspx#vcref_mm_cvttps_epi32

---

Here is a complete implementation which takes 2 x SSE float vectors and converts them to a single packed 8 x 16 bit unsigned vector with wraparound:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>

__m128i vec_float_to_short(const __m128 v1, const __m128 v2)
{
    __m128i v1i = _mm_cvttps_epi32(v1);
    __m128i v2i = _mm_cvttps_epi32(v2);
    v1i = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v1i, _mm_setr_epi8(0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255));
    v2i = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v2i, _mm_setr_epi8(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13));
    return _mm_or_si128(v1i, v2i);
}

int main(void)
{
    __m128 v1 = _mm_setr_ps(0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 32767.0f);
    __m128 v2 = _mm_setr_ps(-32768.0f, 32768.0f, 99999.0f, -99999.0f);
    __m128i v3 = vec_float_to_short(v1, v2);

    printf("v1 = %vf\n", v1);
    printf("v2 = %vf\n", v2);
    printf("v3 = %vhu\n", v3);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this uses `PSHUFB` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) which requires SSSE3 aka SSE3.5 aka MNI (see `tmmintrin.h`), so this will only work on a reasonably current CPU (anything from Intel in the last 6 years or so).

```
$ gcc -Wall -mssse3 vec_float_to_short.c -o vec_float_to_short
$ ./vec_float_to_short 
v1 = 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000 32767.000000
v2 = -32768.000000 32768.000000 99999.000000 -99999.000000
v3 = 0 1 65535 32767 32768 32768 34463 31073
$
```

Note that not all versions of gcc support the printf `v` format specifier for SIMD vectors (I'm using Apple's gcc on OS X in this instance).